# Web2py: how to set contents of a textarea after it is defined

Tags: forms, web2py

I'm using web2py to create an SQLFORM which updates some (currently empty) text fields:

`form = SQLFORM(db.table, db.table(1), fields = ['blank_name'])`

Which creates a textarea tag with `name='blank_name'`. I then want to set the default text for this text area to some variable. So I've tried

`form.element(_name='blank_name').update(_value='My default value')`

but this just sets the 'value' attribute of the textarea to 'My default value'. How can I set the *contents* of the previously blank textarea to a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is simple to set the field default (before creating the form):

```
db.table.blank_name.default = 'My default value'
```

Regarding the original approach, the web2py HTML helpers act like lists with regard to their components (i.e., contents), so you could use the `.append` or `.insert` methods to update the contents.

Comment: I found that the default value approach only works when creating a new row in the DB, not updating an existing one. I also have a different default for each updated row, so the 'default' method seems inappropriate. But form.element(_name='blank_name').append("my text") works fine, and I'm assuming that will be passed on when validating the form. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: True, setting the default won't work when updating an existing record. However, you *can* use the default setting even when you need a different value for each row, as the "default" attribute can be set anywhere in your code, including immediately before the form creation line (i.e., you are not limited to setting the default only once to a single value where the model is first defined).